# What's the difference between WARP drivers,reference drivers and software drivers?

Tags: directx, directx-11

In DirectX 11, there are four types of drivers:

- D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE
- D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE
- D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_SOFTWARE
- D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP

The first one is hardware driver which is widely known to us. and we always use this one in our program. The last 3 are WARP dirver, reference driver and software driver. from the document on MSDN, I am not quite clear what's the differences of the 3 kinds of drivers, the same is they are all implement by software, but, what's the differences?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476328(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I do read this page, it only mentions WARP is high performance and reference and software drives are slow, but what's the differences between reference driver and software driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference device and Software device
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/631456-whats-the-difference-between-d3d-driver-type-software-and-d3d-driver-type-reference/

For WARP device
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615082.aspx

Reference device is provided as pre-release in general (so people can start to write code using full featured api without having hardware support yet), the problem being that reference device (and anything but hardware really) is so slow it's mostly unusable.

Comment: Just in case GameDev.net goes down permanently, I've copied the responses from that thread over to this comment. "Reference Driver" is a development-use driver that come with the DirectX SDK, and is for doing things that the hardware doesn't support yet but will eventually support them later on (experimental features). "Software Driver" is for when you need DirectX on a platform that doesn't support hardware acceleration. It is meant to be fast and easy deployment, and it may or may not implement the features you wanted.