# DirectX11 project failing on Runtime - 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, directx-11

```
for (UINT driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex++)
    {
        _driverType = driverTypes[driverTypeIndex];
        hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(nullptr, _driverType, nullptr, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, numFeatureLevels,
                                           D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &_pSwapChain, &_pd3dDevice, &_featureLevel, &_pImmediateContext);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            break;
    }
```

D3D11CreateDeviceSwapChain returns to hr a value that has not succeeded, which is causing me to not break out of the for loop

`hr` fails the for loop/driver check on all versions of project, even though it only started happening within the last 1-2 iterations.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `0xCDCDCDCD` usually indicates you are dereferncing an uninitalized pointer. Without seeing your code this question can't be really answered.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] so we can actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the error is only occuring because hr has not succeeded - my problem relies on D3D11CreateDeviceSwapChain succeeding.

Comment: Code does run fine on another system using identical VisualStudio, so I'm not sure what's causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to create device and swapchain which is compulsory for any sort of work  i.e drawing. 
It seems like you have a problem in selected driver type

Kindly read details about driver types here [What's the difference between WARP drivers,reference drivers and software drivers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703228/whats-the-difference-between-warp-drivers-reference-drivers-and-software-driver)